# Interval relations

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

To denote interval [a, b] some books use a special symbol.
[image: close]
There are also variants for asymmetrical intervals:
[image: asymmetrical]
How to reproduce them in LaTeX?

My best attempt so far is `a \mathrel{\boldsymbol{^{\vdash}}} b` using amsmath.

Comment: Have you look for it here: http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: I already did but I did not find anything close.

Comment: I just had a quick look too. Maybe not so common then. You might consider giving it up and just used the more common notation instead? Or try PStricks.

Comment: I am typesetting on an old Peano article, I can't change the notations

Comment: @Blincer -- I don't believe these are present in Unicode, but since the reference is historical, they could be submitted for consideration.  For that, an explicit reference is needed -- book/journal name, publisher, date, page number(s); a reference is particularly good if it shows the meaning and context.  If you provide such a reference, I can submit it.

Comment: It is widely used in the Formulario Mathematico (1908) but the first occurrence seems to be in "Notations de logique mathématique" (Turin 1894) page 4.

Comment: Please tell me if you do the submission.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `\rule` for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\linterval}{\mathbin{\rule[1ex]{0.1ex}{0.7ex}\rule[1.2ex]{1ex}{0.3ex}}}
\newcommand{\rinterval}{\mathbin{\rule[1.2ex]{1ex}{0.3ex}\rule[1ex]{0.1ex}{0.7ex}}}
\newcommand{\binterval}{\mathbin{\rule[1ex]{0.1ex}{0.7ex}\rule[1.2ex]{1ex}{0.3ex}\rule[1ex]{0.1ex}{0.7ex}}}
\begin{document}
$a\binterval b$, $a\linterval b$ and $a\rinterval b$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

They can be made very easily adjust to their size of the surroundings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\newcommand{\linterval}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\rule[1ex]{0.2ex}{0.7ex}\rule[1.25ex]{1ex}{0.2ex}}{Q}}}
\newcommand{\rinterval}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\rule[1.25ex]{1ex}{0.2ex}\rule[1ex]{0.2ex}{0.7ex}}{Q}}}
\newcommand{\binterval}{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\rule[1ex]{0.2ex}{0.7ex}\rule[1.25ex]{1ex}{0.2ex}\rule[1ex]{0.2ex}{0.7ex}}{Q}}}
\begin{document}
$a\binterval b$, $a\linterval b$ and $a\rinterval b$.

\Large $a\binterval b$, $a\linterval b$ and $a\rinterval b$.

\tiny  $a\binterval b$, $a\linterval b$ and $a\rinterval b$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm like very much the thickness.

Comment: I finally used those definitions in my document: `\newcommand{\linterval}{\mathbin{\rule[1ex]{0.2ex}{0.7ex}\rule[1.25ex]{1ex}{0.2ex}}}
\newcommand{\rinterval}{\mathbin{\rule[1.25ex]{1ex}{0.2ex}\rule[1ex]{0.2ex}{0.7ex}}}
\newcommand{\binterval}{\mathbin{\rule[1ex]{0.2ex}{0.7ex}\rule[1.25ex]{1ex}{0.2ex}\rule[1ex]{0.2ex}{0.7ex}}}
\newcommand{\ninterval}{\mathbin{\rule[1.25ex]{1ex}{0.2ex}}}` Thanks!

Comment: @Blincer It is very easy to make these adjust to the size of the surroundings, I just did not assume that is a requirement. There are very nice packages for that (and one does not have to start a `\makeatletter` orgy ;-).

Comment: Can you explain how to do so?

Comment: @Blincer I added that to my answer (and also use your dimensions). `scalerel` is a very nice package, and made for this.

Answer (score 3):

I propose to use the `\mapstochar` and `mapsfromchar` glyphs from `mathabx` (without loading the package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{%
 <-6> matha5 
 <6-7> matha6 
 <7-8> matha7 
 <8-9> matha8 
 <9-10> matha9 
 <10-12> matha10 
 <12-> matha12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mapsfromchar}{\mathrel}{matha}{"DF}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varmapstochar}{\mathrel}{matha}{"DE}

\newcommand{\ccintv}{\raisebox{1\jot}{\boldmath$\,\varmapstochar\mkern-0.3mu\relbar\mkern-0.3mu\mapsfromchar\,$}}
\newcommand{\cointv}{\raisebox{1\jot}{\,\boldmath$\varmapstochar\mkern-0.4mu\relbar\mkern1.5mu$}}
\newcommand{\ocintv}{\raisebox{1\jot}{\boldmath$\mkern1.5mu\relbar\mkern-0.3mu\mapsfromchar $\,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
& a \ccintv b &\qquad & a \cointv b &\qquad & a \ocintv b 
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another rule based solution, that doesn't try and guess the symbol's height from the baseline, because it treats it as a superscript. You can easily customize the parameters for the width, the height of the lateral bars and the thickness of the middle bar. These depend on the current font outside math mode, so they adjust automatically to larger or smaller sizes (not the width of the lateral bars, though, with the given implementation but you can decide to express it in `em` units as well).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\intoo}{\peano@interval00}
\newcommand{\intco}{\peano@interval10}
\newcommand{\intoc}{\peano@interval01}
\newcommand{\intcc}{\peano@interval11}

% the width of all symbols em in the current font before the math formula started
\newcommand{\peano@intervalwd}{0.5em}
% the thickness of the bar is 0.25ex in the font for superscripts
\newcommand{\peano@intervalthickness}{0.125ex}% half of the thickness
% the height of the lateral bars is 0.7ex in the font for superscripts
\newcommand{\peano@intervalht}{0.35ex}
\newcommand{\peano@intervalbar}{%
  \vrule height \dimexpr\fontdimen22\scriptfont2+\peano@intervalht\relax
         depth -\dimexpr\fontdimen22\scriptfont2-\peano@intervalht\relax
         width 0.4pt
}

\newcommand{\peano@interval}[2]{{% a mathord
  {\mathstrut}^{%
    \mkern1mu
    \makebox[\peano@intervalwd][s]{%
      \fontsize\sf@size{0}\selectfont
      $\m@th\scriptstyle
      \ifnum#1=1 \peano@intervalbar\fi
      \peano@intervalrule
      \ifnum#2=1 \peano@intervalbar\fi
      $%
    }% end of \makebox
    \mkern1mu
  }% end of superscript
  % remove the \scriptspace
  \kern-\scriptspace
}}
\newcommand{\peano@intervalrule}{%
  \leaders
  \hrule height \dimexpr\fontdimen22\scriptfont2+\peano@intervalthickness\relax
         depth -\dimexpr\fontdimen22\scriptfont2-\peano@intervalthickness\relax
  \hfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\intoo b$

$a\intco b$

$a\intoc b$

$a\intcc b$

\Large
$a\intoo b$

$a\intcc b$

\end{document}
```

[image]